# How to use the split function when trying to split a string by `/` and `|` in Julia

Tags: julia

Does anyone know the appropriate syntax for split when trying to split a string by `/` or `|` (such as vcf file genotypes). I've tried

```
somestring = "1|2|3|4|5"
split(somestring, r"/||")
```

but the double-pipe is clearly incorrect. Thoughts?

[Origional question](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C6A044SQH/p1568593832087800)

Comment: I don't think you should write people's name in these. Just link to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tuple for multiple split characters!

```
julia> split("A/B|C", ('/', '|'))
3-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
```

[Origional Answer](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C6A044SQH/p1568593883088000)

Link to the Julia docs for further reading on `split()` [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split)